# Is there a way to draw a piechart in 3D with matplotlib or any other libarires?

Tags: python, matplotlib

What I want to do is to draw multiple pie charts and layer them in z axis.
So a pie chart would be on top of another one in 3D.
Do you have anything I could refer to maybe using matplotlib or any other python libraries?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.axes(projection='3d')

x = [4,2,5,7,8,2,9,3,7,8]
y = [5,6,7,8,2,5,6,3,7,2]
z = [1,2,6,3,2,7,3,3,7,2]
x2 = [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10]
y2 = [-5,-6,-7,-8,-2,-5,-6,-3,-7,-2]
z2 = [1,2,6,3,2,7,3,3,7,2]

ax1.scatter(x, y, z, c='g', marker='o')
ax1.scatter(x2, y2, z2, c ='r', marker='o')

ax1.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax1.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax1.set_zlabel('z axis')

plt.show()
```

[image]

In the above program, we have taken two sets of variables and plotted each with a different color using the plt.scatter() method.

Comment: sorry, but I'm trying to plot a pie graph in 3D! But thanks for your help anyways :D

Comment: Oh sorry I can't help you about that :(

Comment: No worries! I appreciate your help!! :D

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question (_Is there a way to draw a **piechart** in 3D with matplotlib or any other libraries?_), and should be deleted. The author of this answer even states _Oh sorry I can't help you about that :(_

Answer (score 0):

> There is a 3D library which is "pygooglechart" it's able to draw 3d charts .

```
from pygooglechart import PieChart3D

def pygooglechart_3d_pie() :
    # initialize chart object, 250 x 250 pixels
    chart = PieChart3D(250, 250)    
    # pass your data to the chart object
    chart.add_data([124, 451, 408, 612])    
    # Add the labels for the slices
    chart.set_pie_labels("India UK USA UAE".split()) 
    
    # render the image
    chart.download('demo.png')
pygooglechart_3d_pie()
```